# How do I tune a Ukulele 1 semi-tone higher?

Tags: tuning, alternative-tunings, ukulele

How can I tune a Ukulele so it's one semi-tone higher? Can this be used for 2/3 semi-tones as well?

I've tried using a capo but it makes it a lot harder to play.

Comment: A whole octave! Are you sure you don't want D-tuning which is 2 semi-tones (or one step) higher than the standard C-tuning?

Comment: @Gareth I don't know much (or really anything) about the Uku fretboard + theory so any suggestions are welcome. I had this song in mind: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS7lGaupiFw

Comment: Ahhh... Can't get youtube at work but when I get home I'll check it out...

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if the strings would take a whole octave. That would be a good bit of tension, and ukelele strings are nylon I think. Hopefully it will work though :D.

Comment: Y'know, having watched that video, I don't think it's an octave higher than a uke is usually tuned.  Sounds like a uke in standard tuning.  I mean, ukulele's are already so much smaller than guitars; it's almost as if you took a nylon-string guitar, removed the two bass strings, capo'd it at the 12th fret, and shrunk the body to match.

Comment: @Gareth I've updated to something that won't snap the strings

Comment: Nice to see a ukulele topic on here! I'm a uke-jammer myself!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, So now that I've heard the song you mentioned he is definitely using the D-tuning (A-D-F#-B) that is mentioned below and, I think, with re-entrant tuning. So onward with the breakdown of Ukulele tunings. It would be ideal to use a ukulele pitch pipe to tune but using a standard guitar tuner should work.

I'll start with the standard C tuning. Holding the Ukulele like you're going to play it; from the top string the tuning is:

> G - C - E - A

So essentially if you want a semi-tone up you would use (obviously pitch pipe won't work):

> G# - C# - F - A#

For D-tuning which is quite popular and gives a more "sweeter" higher pitched tone than the standard C you would use (try us the pitch pipe's A note for the top string and tune the rest using it as a reference like you would tune a guitar - http://www.howtotuneaguitar.org/tuning/how-to-tune/ (Guitar tuning)):

> A - D - F# - B:

Now there are two ways of tuning the top string (G-string); "linear" and "re-entrant". Linear is more like a guitar where the top string is lower in pitch than the string below it (C-string). In re-entrant, however the pitch of the G-string is higher than the string below it (So this could be what they mean by an octave up, but its only and octave for the G-string)

*Note: When using re-entrant tuning the G-string is usually a different string type than linear so that it can be tuned up higher than the 2nd string using the linear type G-string would probably just snap it.*

There are other tunings like slack key (G-C-E-G) and one for the baritone uke (D-G-B-E) but I think essentially the most common are the first two.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you should never tune using harmonics other than the octave, always use fretted notes.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Care to elaborate? Ukulele intonation is finicky, and fretted notes are going to be less accurate then on a good guitar.